# MySQL Geometry Limit (Maximum Length of Polygon String)

Tags: mysql, geometry, limit, shapefile

Is there a limitation of how many Points a Polygon may have?

I use shp2mysql-php (http://sourceforge.net/projects/shp2mysql-php/) to import SHP Shape Data of countries. It works fine, but all my polygon date is limited to an maximum length...

Special MySQL Settings:
max_allowed_packet = 10GB

How can insert very long polygon strings?

Comment: Anyone got any answer to this? I experienced the same issue for storing long  WKT format into MySQL